# Which of the surfaces does the vector lie on?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, 3d

[image: Problem description]

So I used the trig identity (y^2 + z^2 = 1) on my y and z component. So I concluded that the cylinder y^2 + z^2 = 4 satisfies the question.

I also concluded that the plane x + y = 3 satisfies the question using the original vector I was given.

I then attempted to graph it, and I am under the impression that it is a sinusoid on the plane x+y = 3. I don't understand how it lies on (y^2 + z^2 = 1), so I'm doubting whether I approached this problem correctly. I thought that for the answer to be E (for the vector to lie on multiple surfaces that the shape would have to be a different shape than a sinusoid.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conclusion that it lies on ii. and iii. is correct. This can be seen by plugging your vector components into each equation:

$y^2+z^2 = (2cos(t))^2+(2sin(t))^2 = 4(sin(t)^2+cos(t)^2) = 4$ and

$x+y = 3-2cos(t)+2cos(t) = 3$.

Comment: Thank you your help Andrew!